# Is there a benefit to one of these statements

Tags: java, optimization

Are there any differences between these two snippets? Performance? Readability? Otherwise?

```
if (arg > 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arg; i++) {
        sb.append(">");
    }
} else if (arg < 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < Math.abs(arg); i++) {
        sb.append("<");
    }
}
```

```
for (int i = 0; i < Math.abs(arg); i++) {
    if (arg > 0) {
        sb.append(">");
    } else if (arg < 0) {
        sb.append("<");
    }
}
```

Personally, I prefer the former, as it more clearly shows that `arg` is a constant.

Comment: view the byte code produced.

Comment: These simply don't make sense.. "0 to arg by 1", but "arg < 0"?

Comment: Neither indicate `arg` is a constant. If you want clarity that `arg` doesn't change then `final` should suffice.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: Forget the bytecode, it says nothing about the hot code execution speed. And if the code isn't hot, forget it altogether.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say that both is pretty unreadable. Anyway, concerning speed:

- First, measure if this part should be optimized at all. Most of the time, the answer is "no".
- If the answer happens to be "yes": Try different variants and measure their performance.

The good thing is that the JIT loves simple and readable code.

I'd go simply for

```
for (int i = 0; i < Math.abs(arg); i++) sb.append(arg > 0 ? ">" : "<");
```

and hope

- that the JIT recognizes that `arg` is a loop invariant
- and `Math.abs(arg)` will be evaluated just once
- and so will `arg > 0 ? ">" : "<"`

If I was crazy after optimization, I'd write

```
char c = arg > 0 ? '>' : '<'; // char instead of String
for (int i = Math.abs(arg); i > 0; i--) sb.append(x);
```

But actually there's a [Guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Strings.html#repeat%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) solution:

```
sb.append(Strings.repeat(arg > 0 ? ">" : "<", Math.abs(arg));
```

Answer (score 2):

If as you stated `arg` is a constant, then the former would be more efficient, because you're only evaluating the if/else condition once, rather than evaluating it every time your loop iterates. However, if arg was not going to be a constant in every loop iteration, then you'd obviously want to go with the latter.

Comment: It won't be more efficient on a modern JVM as it knows it too.

Comment: But it's still bad code. Just because the JVM may clean up your mess doesn't mean that it's logically less efficient.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use any of them; I would try one of the two snippets below.

---

**First variant**

```
    char c = arg > 0 ? '>' : '<';

    int  n = Math.abs(arg);

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(n);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {

        sb.append(c);
    }
```

Here, my suggestions are:

- Prefer primitives to Objects (`char` is likely to be faster than `String`).
- Pre-allocate the buffer if you already know the size (by calling `StringBuffer(int n)`).
- Prefer branch-free loops (better for readability, maintaince and speed).

---

**Second variant**

```
    char c = arg > 0 ? '>' : '<';

    int  n = Math.abs(arg);

    char[] content = new char[n];

    Arrays.fill(content, c);

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(n);

    sb.append(content);
```

Here, my suggestions are:

- Prefer algorithms to self-written loops (the above snippet has no loops at all).
- In particular, `System.arraycopy()` (called by `sb.append(char[] )`) is a native method which doesn't perform bound checks in each iteration.

I personally like this second version better because it is loop-free. It has the downside that it allocates and touches the memory corresponding to the `content` twice: First when the `content` is filled and then when it is copied over into to the `StringBuffer`.

---

Most important of all, profile your code to make sure you are not doing [premature optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization).

*"Want speed? Measure."* (by [Howard Hinnant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/576911/howard-hinnant))

Answer (score 1):

If `arg` is less than 0, the loop won't ever be run, since `i`, being equal to 0 at the start, is certainly not less than 0.

Therefore, the second option is slower if `arg` is less than 0, because it will run through all the options regardless of the fact that it won't ever be true.

Answer (score 1):

I don't like either of them:

- The first, because there is no need to call `Math.abs()` when you already know the sign.
- The second, because it won't terminate if `arg` is negative. So it isn't equivalent to the first in any case. So you're comparing apples and oranges.